# How to hide a window using another thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, notifyicon

I've create a WPF application with `NotifyIcon`, and I use `this.Hide()` to make it minimized, but now I hope it could be minimized once it had been executed, so I invoke `this.Hide()` in the method `MainWindow_Loaded`, but once I start the app, the content of the window turn to be all dark.

Then I try to invoke `this.Hide()` in another thread, and this is what my code looks like...

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
...
   Thread thread = new Thread(DoWork);

   thread.Start();
   Console.WriteLine("thread start");

   while (!thread.IsAlive) ;

   Thread.Sleep(500);

   thread.Join();
   Console.WriteLine("thread has terminated.");
...
}

public void DoWork()
{
    this.Hide();
}
```

then I encounter the problem, when `DoWork()` is invoked, it showed `Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.` What should I do to avoid this? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to `Hide()` your window from another thread? What's the point in this?

Comment: Because I need to hide the window immediately once I start my computer, I invoke Hide() in the MainWindow_Loaded, but it cause my window show nothing but a filled with dark, and that's the reason why I want to do it in this way.

Comment: You should find out why your window does get black rather than invent any multithreading workarounds. I suppose there's something wrong with your code. Your question is a typical [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yeah! At first I invoke Hide() in other place, and it works without any problem; but after I invoke it it MainWindow_Loaded, the problem just happened, but i really NEED to invoke Hide() in MainWindow_Loaded, because I have to minimize my app once the computer has start. Thanks for your advice! I'll learn to clear my question before I search  another way to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Dispatcher object.

```html
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
    {
        // your code
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to use it now!